# Phalcon\Forms\Form bind emtpy field as null

Tags: php, database, phalcon

I have db table like here

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `myVar` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

I'd like to save empty values from $_POST as NULL.

Here is simple code:

```
class MyForm
{
// ...
    public function addInput()
    {
        $t = new Phalcon\Forms\Element\Text('myVar');
        $t->setFilters(['int']);
        // ...
        $this->add($t);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

```
class MyController
{
    public function myFunAction()
    {
        $form = new MyForm();
        $entity = new MyModel();
        if ($this->request->isPost() === true) {
            $post = $this->request->getPost();
            if ($form->isValid($post, $entity) === true && $entity->save()) {
                // OK
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when **myVar** is empty string in text input I have **0** in db table.

Is it better solution to store **NULL** than override **bind** method in myForm class?

Comment: second solution could be somethig like that:
$post = array_map(function($value) {
            return $value ? $value : null;
        }, $post );

Answer (score 1):

The `int` filter from phalcon removes all the characters except digits, plus and minus sign.

This filter is internally based on PHP's [filter_var](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function. So if we use `filter_var`, this is how we can write a filter that returns default value as `null`, if the filter fails

```
<?php

function filter($input) {
    $options = array(
        'options' => array(
            'default' => NULL, // value to return if the filter fails
        ),
    );

    return filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options);
}

var_dump(filter(1)); // Prints 1
var_dump(filter("1")); // Prints 1
var_dump(filter(0)); // Prints 0
var_dump(filter("")); // Prints NULL
```

However Phalcon does not allows you to send all the parameters that `filter_var` actually supports. So **proper way to solve this** is to [Implement your own filter](https://docs.phalcon.io/3.4/en/filter#implementing-your-own-filter) and put the code above.

But if you are feeling lazy, **the lazy way to solve this** is to implement in the proper way, just use this code instead before saving into database.

```
$input = $input === "" ? null : (int) $input;
```

However I recommend that you do it the proper way by implementing `Phalcon\FilterInterface` because it can be re-used.